# Script works with PHP 5.4.16, but not PHP 5.3.3... where is the faulty code?

Tags: php

I'm a beginner in php, and... I was just trying to create this... dynamic indexing/document_display script using php... What I was trying to do isn't really important to the question, however. The thing is... my script does exactly what I want it to do, when hosted on a WAMP server with php 5.4.16... but when uploaded to a LAMP server with php 5.3.3, I get the error

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in
>   /users/clentz/testphpindex.php on line 34

I need it to work on this lamp server.

Can anyone tell me what about the following code is causing errors with the php 5.3.3 interpreter?

```
<?php

$courses_directory = "./Courses";
$courses_array = scandir($courses_directory);

if (empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
{
    include 'Misc/common_components/headers/index_header.html';

    echo "\r\n\t<h1>Enrolled Courses</h1>";

    for ($uwmi_loop_var = 2; isset($courses_array[$uwmi_loop_var]); $uwmi_loop_var++)
    {
        if ($uwmi_loop_var == 2)
        {
            echo "\r\n\t<ul>";
        }

        if (isset($courses_array[$uwmi_loop_var]))
        {
            echo "\r\n\t\t<li>" . '<a href="?' . $courses_array[$uwmi_loop_var] . '">' . $courses_array[$uwmi_loop_var] . '</a></li>';
        }

        if (!isset($courses_array[($uwmi_loop_var + 1)]))
        {
            echo "\r\n\t</ul>\r\n";
        }
    }

    include 'Misc/common_components/footer.html';
}

else if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
{
    for ($uwmi_loop_var = 2; isset($courses_array[$uwmi_loop_var]); $uwmi_loop_var++)
    {
        if (explode("&",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])[0] == rawurlencode($courses_array[$uwmi_loop_var]))
        {
            include "./Courses/" . $courses_array[$uwmi_loop_var] . "/index.php";
        }
    }
}



?>
```

If it helps, you can see the code in a little more visually appealing format at: [pic of the code in a visually appealing format](http://charleselentz.com/fault.png)

Comment: `explode("&",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])[0]` could be the error. +1 for the visually appealing image ;).

Comment: You cannot call array access directly in < 5.4. so your explode[1] will not work, you need to initialise it first

Comment: Man... this is my first day with stack overflow, and I've got to say... could they have made the answers to the question more... 'fine print' like? The responses are in such tiny text, I wish they'd make the answer blocks a little bigger. UGH and if I hit enter, it post my thing, instead of letting me put text on a new line. BUT ANYWAY, you say I can't call the array access directly, and I need to initialize it... how do i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem :**

```
explode("&",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])[0]
```

In PHP 5.3.* version does not support this type of code.

You can do like this for 5.3.* version

```
$query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$arr = explode("&",$query_string);
if ($arr[0] == rawurlencode($courses_array[$uwmi_loop_var]))
{
   include "./Courses/" . $courses_array[$uwmi_loop_var] . "/index.php";
}
```

Comment: OH... so the answers are in big blocks... the other things are comments, like I said, first day with stack overflow... Thanks for this answer, now I see what you guys mean by 'initialize'... I'll implement this, and link to the finished product if it works EDIT: it might take a minute, I only asked the question about one file, but there are a few files with this type of error... I reused code.

Comment: It looks like it's working... but there are going to be many pages to implement this on, but you can see the partial progress at  [link](http://charleselentz.com/clentz_userworld)